# Make label change css while input is in focus

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have a form using Bulma and I want to be able apply the same css classes to the label as I have to the inputs while it's in and out of focus.

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <label class="label is-capitalized">Headline One</label>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control has-icons-right is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input ad-input" >
            <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                <i>5</i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set up a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/21wemLrg/2/

Comment: You will need a script for that, as for focus on input to change the label's style will need the label to be a sibling (positioned after in the markup) of the input

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your javascript:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus',(e)=>{
    document.querySelector('label').classList = '//css classes that you wish to apply';
});

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur',(e)=>{
    document.querySelector('label').classList = '//css classes when the input loses focus';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could solve it using a small js/jquery script like this:

```
 $("input").focus(function() {
   $("label").addClass("input ad-input"); 
 });

 $("input").focusout(function () {
   $("label").removeClass("input ad-input");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way to achieve this with pure css, you will need to change your markup though
https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/vgdpucax/1/

```
<div class="form-inputs">

  <div class="field">
    <div class="ad-input-container control has-icons-right is-expanded">
      <input type="text" class="input ad-input" >
      <span class="icon is-small is-right">
        <i>5</i>
      </span>
      <label class="label is-capitalized">Headline One</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the Css:

```
.ad-input-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.ad-input-container .label {
  order: -1;
}

.ad-input:hover ~ .label, .ad-input:focus ~ .label, .ad-input:active ~ .label {
  color:red;
  /* my custom css for the label */
}
.ad-input-container.control.has-icons-right .icon{
  top:25px;
}
```

The idea is to set your label after your input, in that way you can select your label with the ~ selector once your input is focused...

You can also use flex to change the order where your label appears...